# Change SHA-1 certification debug to release

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-console-developer

I implemented Google Authentication but the problem is i entered the debug version key of SHA-1 certificate, now if i'm gonna create a release version of my app obviously Google Authentication won't work anymore. Any Idea?! i don't want to create a new project again because my app is really complex to start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read **[release certificate:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)**

> The Android SDK tools generate this certificate when you do a release
>   build. You can also generate this certificate using the keytool
>   program. Use this certificate when you are ready to release your app
>   to the world.

You should create **SHA1 KEY** for Release Build . Check <kbd>RELEASE CERTIFICATE TAB</kbd> in above link .

Finally you should add this **build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [mapApiKeyValue: "AIzaSyCcjiArs-4tOeR-9CheiOh8shT9ikh****"]
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [mapApiKeyValue: "AIzaSyCWUAJ5eGSWyTX-FTnZJvT6SF1-*******"]
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Make sure you added like this in Manifest

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${mapApiKeyValue}" />
```

Comment: I already figured it out by importing my project from Google API's console to Firebase at the settings tab next to the overview you can add new SHA keys, anyway thanks!

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya very useful info.  Thank you